# $_FILES['file'] turn null while using filepond

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, filepond

This is the ordinary input file with HTML in the form with method POST

`<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">`

then Ill get that file input with this function written in PHP

```
function Upload() {
    $namefile = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmpName, 'upload/'.$namefile);
    return $namafile;
}
```

Ya that's success. The file move to folder 'upload'.

But I want to try styling my form input with Filepond.

```
<input class="filepond" type="file" name="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
```

With this js

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector(".filepond");
FilePond.registerPlugin(
    FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
    FilePondPluginFileValidateSize
)
FilePond.create(inputElement, {
    labelIdle: 'Upload Photo<span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>',
    maxFiles: '1',
    maxFileSize: '5MB',
    labelMaxFileSizeExceeded: 'Too big bro.',
    labelMaxFileSize: 'max {filesize}',
    labelFileTypeNotAllowed: 'Meh dont up that type',
    fileValidateTypeLabelExpectedTypes: 'just {allTypes}'
})
```

But when I try to get the file with the same method as before, `$_FILES['file']` will just turn null.

Comment: If I remember correctly, if you implement the upload thru filepond, it will be something like `$files = $_FILES["filepond"];` (but please check the documentation again if it is not the case)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of styling your input, filepond may be creating a proxy element with a different name.

Try `var_dump($_FILES)` and see if it has been named something else.

Answer (score 0):

As [browsers cannot update the file input field value](https://pqina.nl/blog/the-trouble-with-editing-and-uploading-files-in-the-browser/) the file is stored in a separate field.

This means you either have to [encode the file](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/plugins/file-encode/) as a base64 string and then upload that with the form submit (and then decode on the server).

Or you have to upload the file asynchronously by setting the [FilePond `server` property](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/) to a page on the server that handles the upload.

A third alternative is setting the `storeAsFile` property to `true`, FilePond will now update the file input field, but this only works if the browser [supports the DataTransfer constructor](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_datatransfer_datatransfer)